# Navigating to a different page based on a timer in MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, timer

I was hoping that I could be able to send a user to a different page if they have not executed any functions in a certain time frame.  Is there some kind of timer that I can execute to accopmlish this?

Thanks,
Derek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [jQuery idle plugin](http://paulirish.com/2009/jquery-idletimer-plugin/).